# NodeJs Loop loading routes: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Trying to load all routes files in `routes` folder using a loop, I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

the code:

```
77 var routes = {};
78 var routeFiles = fs.readdirSync('./routes');
79 for(var i = 0; i < routeFiles.length; i++){
80    if (routeFiles[i].match(/\.js$/) !== null && routeFiles[i] !== 'index.js') {
81        var name = routeFiles[i].replace('.js', '');
82        try {
83            routes[name] = require('./routes/' + name)(passport);
84        } catch (e) {
85            console.log(e.stack);
86        }
87    }
88}
```

the error is at this line:

```
routes[name] = require('./routes/' + name)(passport);
```

And when I write it without loop it works fine, eg:

```
var name = 'main';
routes[name] = require('./routes/' + name)(passport);
```

**EDIT:**

Added Line Numbers.

stacktrace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at Function.handle (/home/burawi/Documents/Dev/daftar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:140:27)
at router (/home/burawi/Documents/Dev/daftar/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
at /home/burawi/Documents/Dev/daftar/app.js:83:59
at tryCatch1 (/home/burawi/Documents/Dev/daftar/node_modules/sequelize-bluebird/js/main/util.js:43:21)
at Promise$_callHandler [as _callHandler] (/home/burawi/Documents/Dev/daftar/node_modules/sequelize-bluebird/js/main/promise.js:639:13)

at Promise$_settlePromiseFromHandler [as _settlePromiseFromHandler] (/home/burawi/Documents/Dev/daftar/node_modules/sequelize-bluebird/js/main/promise.js:653:18)
at Promise$_settlePromiseAt [as _settlePromiseAt] (/home/burawi/Documents/Dev/daftar/node_modules/sequelize-         bluebird/js/main/promise.js:817:14)
at Promise$_settlePromises [as _settlePromises] (/home/burawi/Documents/Dev/daftar/node_modules/sequelize-  bluebird/js/main/promise.js:951:14)
at Async$_consumeFunctionBuffer [as _consumeFunctionBuffer] (/home/burawi/Documents/Dev/daftar/node_modules/sequelize-bluebird/js/main/async.js:75:12)
at Async$consumeFunctionBuffer (/home/burawi/Documents/Dev/daftar/node_modules/sequelize-bluebird/js/main/async.js:38:14)
```

Comment: I would add `console.log(name);` before the line which fails to see what the name is. It could also be that the error is farther up the stacktrace and is in one of the actual routes

Comment: I did that and it doesn't display something weird, just the files' names without '.js'

Comment: can you post a stacktrace? Whatever name it consoles last is the problem child and my guess is the problem is in that file

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that please ?

Comment: When the application crashes it should spit out a stack trace. Another way to do that though is to wrap your code in a try catch, then in the catch statement console.log the stack trace like this: `try { ... } catch(e) {console.log(e.stack);}`